# Make web root folder a sub-folder with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I'm working on a pretty complex project, so I'd like to go with a file/folder structure that makes sense.

**The folder/file structure I'd like to have is:**

```
.htaccess
/php/
/assets/
```

**I'd like to have the web pages that people will access in:**

```
/php/views/pages/
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to use just `.htaccess` to set `/php/views/pages` as the "viewable root", so that for example, when people visit `http://mydomain.com/` they'll be viewing `http://mydomain.com/php/views/pages/index.php`, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Also, is it possible to canonicalize all access to `/php/views/pages` using `.htaccess` and a 301 redirect to stop multiple links being indexed in search engines?

Comment: Why can't you change the `DocumentRoot` directive?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## If you don't have access to your host configuration

[`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) can only be used in server and virtual host configs, .htaccess it must be.

1. Let's add directives in your .htaccess

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   ```
2. I assume you want to let the requests to /assets go through

   ```
   #if a match for asset is found, do nothing
   RewriteRule ^assets/ - [L]
   ```
3. If a request tries to access `/php/views/pages/` directly, redirect it to its canonical version

   ```
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} php/views/pages/
   RewriteRule ^php/views/pages/(.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```
4. And add a rule to map everything else to `/php/views/pages/`

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !php/views/pages/
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /php/views/pages/$1 [L]
   ```

## If you have access to your host configuration

Forget about .htaccess files and use it. A sample configuration could look like

```
# ~base stands for your original DocumentRoot
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot ~base/php/views/pages
    Alias /assets ~base/assets

    # other configuration parameters
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Brilliant. There's a time cap on the bounty, so I'll award it to you when it finishes :). Thanks a lot for the very explanatory answer.