# .htaccess map subdirectory as root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-mapping

I found a question similar to this but doesn't seem to work for me ( [Make web root folder a sub-folder with .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364951/make-web-root-folder-a-sub-folder-with-htaccess)). So i'm asking for help after not being able to find any answers to my problem -- i spent 2 hours going through 200+ pages of results on stackoverflow before giving up. Anyways...

I'm creating a small CMS and have my directory structure setup like this:

```
application
-- html
-- -- public
-- -- -- theme
-- -- -- -- css
-- -- -- -- images
-- -- -- -- js
-- -- -- forum
-- -- -- -- index.php
-- -- -- -- viewforum.php
-- -- -- -- viewthread.php
-- -- -- -- comment.php
-- -- -- index.php
-- -- -- login.php
-- -- -- profile.php
-- -- admincp
-- -- -- theme
-- -- -- -- css
-- -- -- -- images
-- -- -- -- js
-- -- -- index.php
-- -- -- manage.php
-- -- -- users.php
-- -- -- settings.php
-- plugins
library
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to map mydomain.com/application/html/public/index.php to mydomain.com/index.php and with admincp its mydomain.com/admincp/index.php. So that it looks like everything in the public directory is located in the root directory.

At the moment when i view mydomain.com it shows the index.php file from ../public/ but when i try mydomain.com/index.php i get a not found error. When I go to mydomain.com/admincp or mydomain.com/admincp/manage.php it works though-- if you know of a way of making it better let me know. :)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ application/html/public/
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/html/public/$1 # Breaks site

RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admincp  !-f
RewriteRule ^admincp/(.*)? application/html/admincp/$1
RewriteRule ^admincp$ admincp/ [L]
```

I'd appreciate any help,advice, sarcasm that I can get on this issue.

**-- EDIT --**

@Michael provided me with an answer that served my purpose
 This was the result:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't need this...
#RewriteRule ^$ application/html/public/

# Need [L] and a RewriteCond
# Don't do the rewrite if this is an actual existing file
# such as what is rewritten into application/html/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# And don't write admincp into public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !admincp
# With the above conditions met, write anything else into the public dir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/html/public/$1 [L]

# Then just write admincp into application/html/admincp
RewriteRule ^admincp/(.*) application/html/admincp/$1 [L]
```

Now I just need to fix the problem where my directory index is displayed when viewing the root -- mydomain.com/

**-- EDIT --**

When i added back in 
`RewriteRule ^$ application/html/public/`
It didn't break, so its lookin like it works like it should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A missing `[L]` flag and a rewrite loop when `public/` is matched, is likely the cause of your site breaking.  The first of your two rules for the public area is unnecessary if the second is done correctly:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't need this...
#RewriteRule ^$ application/html/public/

# Need [L] and a RewriteCond
# Don't do the rewrite if this is an actual existing file
# such as what is rewritten into application/html/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# And don't write admincp or others into public

# Add each area you need to exclude into the () below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(admincp|formus|otherarea1|otherarea2)

# With the above conditions met, write anything else into the public dir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application/html/public/$1 [L]

# Then just write admincp into application/html/admincp
#RewriteRule ^admincp/(.*) application/html/admincp/$1 [L]
# Update: Instead of the above rule, if you need additional rules like forums
# make the final rule generic to capture the directory in ([^/]+):
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) application/html/$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: It works! but when i add in stuff like `RewriteRule ^forum/$ application/html/public/forum.php [L]` the new rule doesnt work. :(

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm starting to understand htaccess a bit better.