# htaccess rewrite rule accesing folder without redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an root folder like this:

```
ROOT
|- Service
|  |- Admin
|
|- Service 2
```

I'm interesting in accessing the `admin` folder from service folder

To access the admin path via url i use `mydomain.com/Service/Admin`

Is there any way to make it access like this `mydomain.com/Admin` without moving folders?

I got the answer from one guy and is working, but is not working if i don't add / at the end of Admin

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(Admin/.*)$ Service/$1 [L,NC]
```

`mydomain.com/Admin/` - working

`mydomain.com/Admin` - not working (404 error)

I want both to work

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/` from the redirect rule? Meaning, something like this `RewriteRule ^(Admin.*)$ Service/$1 [L,NC]` ?

Comment: That works, but will redirect my url to `mydomain.com/Service/Admin` and i don't want that

Comment: How about this: `RewriteRule ^Admin.*$ http://mydomain.com/Service/Admin/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Hmm, that was close, i made it like this

`RewriteRule ^Admin$ http://mydomain.com/Admin/ [L,NC]` and this will redirect me to `http://mydomain.com/Admin/` workin url

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364951/make-web-root-folder-a-sub-folder-with-htaccess it should be helpful for you,

Comment: Or this one: https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules

Answer (score 0):

I made is like this and is working

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Admin$ http://mydomain.com/Admin/ [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(Admin/.*)$ Service/$1 [L,NC]
```