# Remove .php from URL - Specific case

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess file, everything works so far but I can't manage to remove .php extension from files, every code that I tried from other answers just threw 500 or 404 error. Please advise where and what to add. Structure of the folders is localhost/myfolder/somefile.php

Just to be clear - localhost/myfolder/ is a root for my project.

```
RewriteEngine On     

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfolder/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule     ^team-news/([0-9]+[/])?$    posts.php?p=$1&cat=Team\ News
RewriteRule     ^product-news/([0-9]+[/])?$    posts.php?   p=$1&cat=Product\ News
RewriteRule     ^member-specials/([0-9]+[/])?$    posts.php?p=$1&cat=Member\ Specials
RewriteRule     ^ambassador-blogs/([0-9]+[/])?$    posts.php?p=$1&cat=Ambassador\ Blogs
RewriteRule     ^user/([0-9]+[/])?$         profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule     ^browse-all/([0-9]+[/])?$   searchall.php?p=$1
RewriteRule     ^edit/([0-9]+[/])?$         edit.php?id=$1
RewriteRule     ^articles/([0-9]+[/])?$     post.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Not sure what you do wrong, but there are some tools like [this](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) that might be able to help you out..

Comment: Can you clarify what the error is and which URL isn't working?

Comment: The code that is posted here all works, but now I need to insert a part which removes .php from the files, and whatever I try just won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will allow you to rewrite to remove `php` extensions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If you want your URL to have a trailing `/`, you can use this snippet:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

[Source](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Answer (score 0):

Removing extension, say; php or html in browser will let browser find it a little bit more effort to find the source file. if you need it so, this follows may help you:

UPDATED:

**PHP:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php
```

**HTML:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.html
```

those will remove all extensions in your files (both php and html).
**Note**: see if server **enables mod rewrite module/extension**.

Comment: This gives me infinite loop, for example the /myfolder/search.php path it goes to /myfolder/search/.php/.php/.php/ to the infinity

Comment: I updated my answer, see if it helps. don;t forget to check if server (apache/else) enables you to have the action

Comment: I checked, it does. The rules you see I posted all work, for example localhost/myfolder/user/6/ is working. Adding trailing slash rule works too. But whatever rule I insert to remove .php it throws an error. Maybe it's interfering with some of my other rules?

Comment: Yes, it's the whole file for now.

Comment: do you have access in the web root, I mean at localhost, not folder. ?

Comment: Yes I do, it's XAMPP that I set up to develop an app for a client. Never messed with rewrites before.

Comment: Then, try to remove 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f' 
above
'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$' 
and try this tips> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364951/make-web-root-folder-a-sub-folder-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Just below your `301` rule add this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder/

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: It gives me 404 error, for example for /myfolder/search.php path it goes to /myfolder/search/ but with 404

Comment: Still nothing, now it adds a /.php/ to my other urls, and throws 404 error for php files. Maybe I am doing something wrong in my other rules that messes everything else up?

Comment: These 2 rules work fine for me. Comment out your trailing slash 301 rule and retest. Where is this .htaccess located? Inside `myfolder` or a level above it?

Comment: When I remove slash 301 rule and insert these two I get 404 errors. .htaccess is located inside myfolder - which should act as a root of my project. I am doing it that way because whole project will be located inside a separate folder on a domain.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using two `.htaccess` files. The first should go in your localhost root (to redirect requests to `myfolder`), and the second should go into `myfolder` (to match up routes against your PHP files):

**Root `.htaccess`:**

```
RewriteEngine On     

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfolder/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

**myfolder `.htaccess`:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder/

RewriteRule ^team-news/([0-9]+[/])?$         posts.php?p=$1&cat=Team\ News [L]
RewriteRule ^product-news/([0-9]+[/])?$      posts.php?p=$1&cat=Product\ News [L]
RewriteRule ^member-specials/([0-9]+[/])?$   posts.php?p=$1&cat=Member\ Specials [L]
RewriteRule ^ambassador-blogs/([0-9]+[/])?$  posts.php?p=$1&cat=Ambassador\ Blogs [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+[/])?$              profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^browse-all/([0-9]+[/])?$        searchall.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/([0-9]+[/])?$              edit.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+[/])?$          post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Note how I have also included `[L]` to stop it from doing anything else once it has found a match.