# Redirecting subdomain to a folder inside main that contains a CakePHP app

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

Have tried a lot of examples here in SO but none seem to work. Consider my set up:

```
/public_html/
     /app/
     /cgi-bin/
     /lib/
     /plugins/
     /revamp/
     /vendors/
```

I currently have a cakephp website `site.com` that has its files under `/app/` folder, and the .htaccess I use right now looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
  RewriteEngine on

  ReWriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
  ReWriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to redirect the subdomain `revamp.site.com` to the folder `/revamp/` which would be another cakephp site.

## UPDATE 1:

Been asked to create a vhost and i did, it is set to the subdomain folder, the help I want is for a htaccess rule to work for both, the one above and also redirect to subdomain if the requested address has the subdomain on it before the domain...

## UPDATE 2:

The following `.htaccess` gets me to my subdomain, but only to the index.html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^revamp\.site\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) revamp/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Its a mix of the two answers...though whatever path I put with subdomain, it only will get me to index.html (as it is hardcoded in the htaccess). Tried also  `revamp/$` and  `revamp/$1` with no luck.

## UPDATE 3:

Tried this with edit of first answer:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   #subdomain simple site
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.test\.com$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain
   RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ subdomain/$1 [L]
   
   #cakephp site
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Still gives a 500, I also tried switching positions of both blocks

## Update 4:

WORKING solution, having both cakephp sites under `/public_html/app` and `/public_html/revamp/app`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^revamp\.site\.com$
   RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ revamp/app/webroot/$1 [NC,L]

   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: are you using a shared hosting?

Comment: Set up another VirtualHost for revamp and set DocumentRoot to be /revamp

Comment: @DavidAguilar I'm using a VPS yes

Comment: @user2182349 I keep getting told my the webhost to not change the root from vhost since it'll get reset everytime apache needs rebuild, they advise me for a htaccess extra rule to direct traffic looking for the subdomain

Comment: Wouldn't this work more easily by putting revamp into the app/webroot folder of the first one? Is there a reason not to do it that way?

Comment: @ChrisF any success?

Comment: Because you are using shared host, i think best place to ask this question is their support. From my experience, procedure differs from provider to provider, and most of them have some UI option to do this..

Comment: @sitilge sorry man, I have been really busy, I infact tried both the answers I got, which yielded no succesfull result =/

Comment: @NickZinger because /app/ is under CakePHP framework, it will try to resolve it under the rules of the framework if I put /revamp/ under that folder

Comment: it seems RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L] is wrong, can you try it with some virtual host like RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ for cakephp site

Comment: @ChetanAmeta the cakephp site loads perfectly, the one that gives me 500 is the subdomain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achive required rewriting by using "Rewrite condition" for different different domain:

At my machine I cretaed a folder structure like

```
public_html
 -app
   -webroot
 -local
   -app
     -webroot
```

app, webroot and local directory in `public_html` folder and then app and webroot directory in local folder.

Now I created a virtual host entry as below:

```
<VirtualHost test.com:80>
 ServerName test.com
 ServerAlias local.test.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Means `test.com` and `local.test.com` both pointed at `public_html` directory.

Now your aim is, if domain is `test.com` then outer app should run and if domain is `local.test.com` then your inner(local folder) app should run.

As structure of `.htaccess` in cakephp i placed `.htaccess` file in both `app` and `webroot` folder of both application.

code of `.htaccess` in `app/` directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

code of `.htaccess` in `webroot/`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

now the changes in `.htaccess` of root directory i.e. `public_html`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   #for test.com
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$
   RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [NC,L]

   #for local.test.com
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\.test\.com$
   RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ local/app/webroot/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

1. RewriteCond `%{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$` will identify that domain is `test.com`
2. RewriteCond `%{HTTP_HOST} ^local\.test\.com$` will identify that
   domain is `local.test.com`

**For general sub domain rewrite you can use follow code:**

Folder structure:

```
public_html
 -index.html
 -subdomain
  --index.html
```

Code of `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   #for subdomain.test.com
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.test\.com$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain
   RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ subdomain/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

now test.com will open `index.html` of `public_html` folder while `subdomain.test.com` will open `index.html` of `subdomain` folder

**Update Answer 2**

I created exact directory structure mentioned in question, and below htaccess code works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$
   RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [NC,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^revamp\.test\.com$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/revamp
  RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ revamp/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Instead of a cakephp site inside subdomain, it tried a simple index.html file

Comment: @ChrisF it will works for folder structure of cakephp as i created structure like mentioned above, for simple folder you need to change the code in htaccess file

Comment: @ChrisF please see revised answer

Comment: @ChrisF use last .htaccess code for subdomain, hope it will work for you

Comment: @ChrisF have you tried my second solution with RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain which I updated yesterday?

Comment: yeah man, my comment above yours telling you i tried and update my answer with your update

Comment: So i'm very close, the error now with your last edit is: 404 The requested URL /revamp/ was not found on this server.

Comment: @ChrisF thats great, can you tell me on which directory your domain `revamp.test.com` is pointed?

Comment: Its pointed at /revamp/ just as the file structure on the question

Comment: The htaccess used is the one under /public_html/.htaccess

Comment: Working man, thanks! Question: the rule RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ only allows for test.com access and not for www.test.com access, what rule would allow for both?

Comment: @ChrisF can you try with 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^revamp\.site\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) revamp.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ revamp [L]
```

However, I would create a trivial new `VirtualHost` to handle requests to the subdomain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName revamp.site.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/public_html/revamp
    <Directory>
        #your other rewrite rules here
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

References:

- [Make web root folder a sub-folder with .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364951/make-web-root-folder-a-sub-folder-with-htaccess/10427485#10427485)
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/how-to-redirect-requests-to-another-folder-using-htaccess

Comment: I'm getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS from this solution