# .htaccess - hide Joomla 3 installation directory from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I just created a Joomla 3 site (offline at the moment). Joomla was installed at `www.mydomain.com/jo/` directory, and at `.htaccess` file I included the following rule to redirect from `www.mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com/jo/`, and it's working fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ jo [L]
```

I'm using URL Rewriting also working great after making adjustment at `.htaccess`

I searched for two days how to get rid of /Jo directory in URL. I found a code which work partially:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule !^jo(/.*)?$ /jo%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^jo(/(.*))?$ /$2 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is it hide the directory on website landing page / homepage, as menu item or article is selected it show directory in URL.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to remove /jo/ dir completly from your urls :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /jo/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^((?!jo).*)$ /jo/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I forgot to indicate .htaccess include RewriteBase /jo in order to set Use URL rewritting by Joomla

Answer (score 0):

in configuration.php you need to set

```
$live_site = "http://www.example.com";
```

(SO dont allow mydomain.com)

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894760/install-joomla-in-a-subdirectory/35047905#35047905) for more info: