# The transition effect of Stackoverflows' shared answer

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, transition, target

We always ask questions about our own sites and particular circumstances. I thought it would be interesting to ask a question about a site we all know: Stackoverflow.com.

When you share an answer on Stackoverflow (under an answer click "share") you get a link. It looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442900

Then open the link and you see the shared answer lights up a few seconds.

Any creative thinkers who know how to replicate this effect? Another version of the STACKOVERFLOW effect would be welcome, but I'm curious if there's anybody who can make it exactly as the example of the STACKOVERFLOW team (this makes the difference compared to other related questions on Stackoverflow about this matter).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as a side note, you can question related to the website on the meta site https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thank you Temani for the tips. I didn't know about the meta site, but now I do. Regarding the other posts, I think you are right, but the only difference is that in this case it's about the STACKOVERFLOW effect, which the other posts are not.

Comment: well you don't need to find a post with EXACTLY the same effect ... the question above give a hint/clue on how it's done then it's CSS ;) up to you to modify to create your own effect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always take a look at the [used CSS](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css), as this is not encrypted in any way.

There you can find something like `animation-name:blinking`, which I guess is what you're looking for.

The background-color for the given element is set to a specific color and the opacity is increased. That's how the effect is made.